# Java FileOutputStream writing negative byte values writing wrong bytes

Tags: java, serialization, fileoutputstream, negative-number

I came to a problem with writing negative byte values into binary file using FileOutputStream, where negative byte values, ex. -1 is written into file but it takes there two bytes and they seem to me to be completely nonsense.

In my application I have toByteArray() on some objects returning byte[] so I can write it into a file. Even though it "works" on many objects I got object that gets serialized to byte array where there are some negative bytes (new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 3, -48, -5, 10}) and when I write this object into a file the negative ones are written there as "c0 a2" bytes.

Test case:

```
public void testWRITE() {
    String fileName = "TEST_FILE.lldb";
    String secondFileName = "SECOND_FILE.lldb";
    FileOutputStream fos;
    FileOutputStream fos2;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName, false);
        fos2 = new FileOutputStream(secondFileName, false);

        // Writing this to file writes bytes "c2 a0" in place of -1 byte
        FileChannel ch = fos.getChannel();
        ch.position(0);
        ch.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 3, -48, -5, 10}));


        // Writing this to file writes "ff" in of -1 byte
        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
        FileChannel ch2 = fos2.getChannel();
        ch2.position(0);
        ch2.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(pojo.getBytes()));

        fos.close();
        fos2.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        fail();
    }
}
```

where Pojo class is simple POJO as

```
public class Pojo {

    private Integer negativeNumber;

    public Pojo() {
        this.negativeNumber = -1;
    }

    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return Pojo.bytesFromInt(this.negativeNumber);
    }

    public static byte[] bytesFromInt(int value) {
         return new byte[] {
            (byte)(value >>> 24),
            (byte)(value >>> 16),
            (byte)(value >>> 8),
            (byte)value};
    }}
```

As I am counting on a fact that when I write one byte to a file it will be just one byte I can't proceed further with my work as it's a building stone of my library.

Wrong bytes instead of negative numbers
[image: Wrong bytes instead of negative numbers]

Writing serialized POJO with negative integer converted to byte array
[image: Writing serialized POJO with negative integer converted to byte array]

Is that even considered as expected behaviour of FileOutputStream?
What am I missing?

Comment: There is no such thing as a byte bigger than 127 in Java. They are signed, so their values are -128..127. All you are seeing here is sign extension.

Comment: Are you sure that is the code which is generating that output?  When I run that code, the resulting file contains: 00 00 00 01 ff ff ff ff  01 03 d0 fb 0a

Comment: I am certain about it I even tried it on friends machine with same result. What jdk did you use? That's all I can think of could be causing this. And user207421s answear is just not correct but whatever.

Comment: I used OpenJDK 11.0.3, but I doubt that’s the issue.  If a FileChannel or FileOutputStream were corrupting bytes, I think it would have gained a lot of attention by now.  Are you making use of Strings anywhere?  ‘c2 a0’ looks like a UTF-8 sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is written correctly.

When you write negative numbers you are writing them in two's complement form.

So writing  `-5` = `1111 1011` which is `FB` in hex.  That is what you are seeing.

And `FF` = `1111 1111` = `-1`.

Here is the modified code I used to check your results. Note that I added a logical file letter to the filenames.  Perhaps I am doing something wrong.

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Writing {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      testWRITE();

   }

   public static void testWRITE() {
      String fileName = "F:/TEST_FILE.lldb";
      String secondFileName = "F:/SECOND_FILE.lldb";
      FileOutputStream fos;
      FileOutputStream fos2;
      try {
         fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName, false);
         fos2 = new FileOutputStream(secondFileName, false);

         // Writing this to file writes bytes "0c2 a0" in place of -1 byte
         FileChannel ch = fos.getChannel();
         ch.position(0);
         System.out.println("Writing to " + fileName);
         ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(
               new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 3, -48, -5, 10
               });

         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b.array()));
         ch.write(b);
         // Writing this to file writes "ff" in of -1 byte
         Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
         FileChannel ch2 = fos2.getChannel();
         ch2.position(0);
         System.out.println("Writing to " + secondFileName);
         ch2.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(pojo.getBytes()));
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pojo.getBytes()));

         fos.close();
         fos2.close();

         System.out.println();
         FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
         FileInputStream fs2 = new FileInputStream(secondFileName);
         System.out.println("Reading all bytes from " + fileName);
         byte[] bs = fs.readAllBytes();
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bs));
         System.out.println("Reading all bytes from " + secondFileName);
         bs = fs2.readAllBytes();
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bs));
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}

class Pojo {

   private Integer negativeNumber;

   public Pojo() {
      this.negativeNumber = -1;
   }

   public byte[] getBytes() {
      return Pojo.bytesFromInt(this.negativeNumber);
   }

   public static byte[] bytesFromInt(int value) {
      return new byte[] {
            (byte) (value >>> 24), (byte) (value >>> 16), (byte) (value >>> 8),
            (byte) value
      };
   }
}
```

Here is my output.

```
Writing to F:/TEST_FILE.lldb
[0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 3, -48, -5, 10]
Writing to F:/SECOND_FILE.lldb
[-1, -1, -1, -1]

Reading all bytes from F:/TEST_FILE.lldb
[0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 3, -48, -5, 10]
Reading all bytes from F:/SECOND_FILE.lldb
[-1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Comment: No it's not mate. That byte array I inicialized has 13 bytes yet in file there are 19 as negative numbers are written really oddly.

Comment: I wrote out the bytes as they were defined before you wrote them to the files.  Then I read them back in as byte arrays and printed them out.  What was written and what was read were identical.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is kinda awkward as I am not just a beginner programmer but yes I was wrong there. When I read that file back to memory there are really just those bytes I had written into file before. But to support my post and attitude, I wasn't really running any other code only that that was posted. But viewing that file using Notepad++ with HEXEditor extension really shows me "FF" and "C2 A0" and I can't figure out why even though when I read file back to memory the bytes are "just bytes" but when I saw "C2 A0" in file I did not even think of reading it back to memory to check it. CaptainObvious mentioned doing UTF-8 conversion "somewhere" but if that's the case it's just not in my code.